# How to use SQLite db with QGIS plugin?

Tags: python, qgis, plugins, sqlite

I would like to use SQLite for storing some information in my plugin for QGIS.

I have a problem: if I put the db, let say test.db, among the resources as file, after compiled the resorce.qrc file, QGIS find the db, but if I insert some row in the db, QGIS does not find any more I have to compile again the file,  I tried to recompile the file every time I commit something in the db, it seems to work, but is a dirty solution and I do not think I can use it on every system different from the mine, is there a better solution?

Answer (score 1):

Don't put your sqlite database into a resource file, that's a really bad idea.  You are converting the database into readonly binary data in your resource.py.

**EDIT:** Seems Qt resources are not meant just for storing strings.  Use QSettings instead.

You should store the connection string (if needed) then just connect using something like [sqlite3](http://docs.python.org/library/sqlite3.html) in the standard python libs.

```
import sqlite3
from PyQt4.QtCore import QSettings
settings = QSettings()
connstring = settings.value("myConnectionString").toString()
conn = sqlite3.connect(connstring)
```

myConnectionString is defined in your settings ini/registry file as a string.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I understand that putting the sqlite database into aresource file is a very bad idea, it does not work either, my problem is that my plugin does not find the db if this is not into the resources file, so I need a way to access the db from my plugin, I found a dirty way to do it: I put a small script in python into the  resources file, the script; the plugin calls the script and receives the results as it was on the command line, I do not like this way because, it works only if I launch qgis from the directory where the sqlite database is and is very slow

Comment: Can you post a code sample of what you are doing and where the db is located relative to the file calling it.

Comment: Hi the db was in the same directory of the plugin, this is the command I used to query the db# text= getstatusoutput(command line # in the command line I put "python myscript.py arguments" myscript query the db  and does some outputs that is put in text, so I could write and read sqlite, but now I use Qsettings for all I need to save.